# Is ROS 2 due to replace ROS 1?

Tags: ros

I have read *ROS 2* document and they did not give many clues on the subject.

Does anybody have more insight on the subject?

Comment: It's the long term plan, but so far, the incentive for most ROS1 users to switch is not high enough.

Comment: @FooBar if you can provide a reference, then you should post an answer.

Comment: This is agreed indeed!

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://design.ros2.org/articles/why_ros2.html)

> In principle, the changes described above could be integrated into the
>   existing core ROS code. E.g., new transport technologies could be
>   added to roscpp and rospy. We considered this option and concluded
>   that, given the intrusive nature of the changes that would be required
>   to achieve the benefits that we are seeking, there is too much risk
>   associated with changing the current ROS system that is relied upon by
>   so many people. We want ROS 1 as it exists today to keep working and
>   be unaffected by the development of ROS 2. So ROS 2 will be built as a
>   parallel set of packages that can be installed alongside and
>   interoperate with ROS 1 (e.g., through message bridges).

I don't see this happening soon, but I can imagine this happening in the future. For now, ROS 2 will be developed in parallel with ROS 1 and as such these are two different projects. As like other projects in the past (the one that comes to my mind is Python 2 vs Python 3) they are supported (including releases of new features) for a long period but at some point the community wants to focus on one. I think this will happen with ROS 2 once ROS 2 reach a stable and mature state and when most of the people start using ROS 2.

Comment: I would also like to add that the first "normal" release of ROS2 is Diamond Diadimata. Looking at the release schedules of [ROS 1](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions), ROS 2 Diamond is now on a 2 year support [schedule](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/), just like ROS 1 used to be, so I would say the release of Ros 2 Diamond means that ROS 1 has been replaced. I am not sure they have made any official announcements any other way other than the release schedules of ROS 1 and 2. ROS 1 is also not releasing any more new versions, so you should probably learn ROS 2.